# How to upload Map<DateTime, List<String>> to firebase and load it from firebase as Map<DateTime, List<String>>?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a data structure of type `Map<DateTime, List<String>>` like:

```
{2022-05-26 00:00:00.000Z: [10: 00 AM, 1: 00 PM], 2022-05-30 00:00:00.000Z: [11: 00 PM]}
```

I have declared it like so:

```
Map<DateTime, List<String>> selectedEvents = {};
```

This is the code from which I get an error while uploading to firebase:

```
class BookingService {
  static Future sendDoctorSchedule(Map<DateTime, List<String>> events) async {
    try {
      final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      print(events);
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bookings').doc(user!.uid).set(events as Map<String, List<String>>);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      throw CustomException(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

The error is:

> Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<String>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, List<String>>' in type cast.

How do I upload this to firebase and once uploaded, how do I load it as the type Map<DateTime, List<String>> from firebase on initial load? Could you please provide sample code?

Comment: You have to convert that datetime to either String or to timestamp and then upload to firebase, reverse the process when received from firebase to get data as per your requirement

Comment: How do you cast Map<DateTime, List<String>> to the appropriate type on dart?

Comment: You cant use the Datetime Map for uploading to firebase as it uses timestamp to store datetime

Answer (score 0):

To convert Datetime to Timestamp for storing to firebase

```
final int currentDate = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

// This will result in something like this 1653653820000

// To revert back from Timestamp to Datetime

```
final Datetime datetime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(currentDate);
```

// Workaround for the code provided

```
try {
      final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      print(events);
      Map<int, List<String>> newMap = {};
      events.forEach((key, value) {
      newMap[key.millisecondsSinceEpoch] = value;
      });
      awaitFirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bookings').doc(user!.uid).set(newMap);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      throw CustomException(e.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm a beginner. I'm also not sure on how to implement it when it's under Map<DateTime, List<String>>. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: give me a minute I am posting the solution

Comment: Can you provide the code where you have called this sendDoctorSchedule(Map<DateTime, List<String>> events)

Comment: I have posted a workaround for the code in question

Comment: why have you used events[value], as you need to use only value

Comment: I called it on an async function of onPress event to send the schedules set             await BookingService.sendDoctorSchedule(selectedEvents);

Comment: I get  Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: Map<int, List<String>> corrected = {};
      events.forEach((key, value){
        corrected[key.millisecondsSinceEpoch] = value;
      });

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bookings').doc(user!.uid).set({'events': corrected});

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I had to cast the int to String.